# PHP Form SQL Format Error

Tags: php, html, database, forms

I am trying to make a simple form that checks based on the correct email. If the email is correct, it then updates the database with the new time. When I run it, I get a format error.. I am not an expert with PHP, so I may have missed something here...

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'user1';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$email= $_POST['email'];
$time= $_POST['time'];

$sql = "UPDATE users".
       "SET time= $time".
       "WHERE email = $email" ;

mysql_select_db('dbname');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">Email:</td>
<td><input name="email" type="text" id="email"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Time:</td>
<td><input name="time" type="text" id="time"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what error you are getting??

Comment: Could not update data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 12WHERE email = test@gmail.com' at line 1

Comment: Use `$sql = "UPDATE users SET time= '$time' WHERE email = '$email'";`

Comment: Now I get the error: Could not update data: No database selected. I am sure I have the right database name...

Comment: Consult [`my answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22651714/) below. @AubtinSamai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query has the wrong quotes.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'user1';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('dbname');

$email= $_POST['email'];
$time= $_POST['time'];

$sql = "UPDATE users SET time= '$time' WHERE email = '$email'";

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">Email:</td>
<td><input name="email" type="text" id="email"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Time:</td>
<td><input name="time" type="text" id="time"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Sidenote: Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) functions. (which I recommend you use and with [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo))

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

---

Quick note(s)

You could shorten your code by doing the following all in one go:

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'user1';
$dbpass = 'password';
$db = 'dbname';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db);
```

so you won't have to use `mysql_select_db('dbname');` but that's purely opinion-based/preference and will save you a few keystrokes at the same time.

---

Changing:

```
$email= $_POST['email'];
$time= $_POST['time'];
```

to:

```
$email= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$time= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['time']);
```

will help add a bit of security until you get into prepared statements or PDO.

Comment: although bad form, why does the order matter if he is just defining $sql before he selects the db. he doesn't run the query until he has selected the db

Comment: It works now.. Thanks a lot! I will work on the security later, just getting it to function properly first.

Comment: I always thought that DB selection made a difference. @CameronAziz I've modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Hanky웃Panky I will also. I've learned a bit more tonight.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have spaces in your sql script.

change `$sql` to:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users ".
   "SET time= '$time' ".
   "WHERE email = '$email'" ;
```

although this will work just fine:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET time= '$time' WHERE email = '$email'" ;
```

keep in mind, your page is vulnerable to sql injection because you have not escaped time and email.

Comment: And what about enclosing string values in quotes?